# Can we use both dnf and Microdnf simultaneously?

Tags: package-management, rpm, dnf

I am getting below error message when I use dnf and microdnf simultaneously to install/remove packages.

**error: failed loading RPMDB**

Comment: Many package managers will lock the database of installed packages for their exclusive use while they're running. I guess it's seen as an issue that's not deemed critical, as the number of people authorized to install packages is usually small. So, I wouldn't be not surprised, but the error message could probably be better. (You do mean simultaneous as in "dnf installs and at the same time, microdnf wants to remove", not just "I have both and want to use whichever I like more today", right?)

Answer (score 0):

In the [Debian](https://debian.org) world, when you try to run [Synaptic](https://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) and do an [apt-get install](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt) at the same time, the first one to the package database wins; it locks the database first, and the app launched later loses.

The same thing happens in the RedHat/CentOS/Fedora world. You can run [dnf](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF?rd=Dnf) or [Microdnf](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/microdnf) or [Yum](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Yum), but not simultaneously. You must wait for one to complete before launching the other.